# How to get a computer's Distinguished Name (DN) with C++

Tags: c++, winapi, active-directory, domaincontroller, distinguishedname

I can't seem to find a way to get a DN of a workstation (computer) with C++ and WinAPIs. Any ideas how to do this?

PS. The workstation is connected to a domain controller.

PS2. I need the DN of a computer and not the logged on user.

Comment: For clarification, do you want the name of the computer *your code is running on*? Or the name of any arbitrary computer whose alternate Id you specify (such as a NetBIOS name, DNS name, etc) ? It makes a difference.

Comment: I need it for computer that my code is running on. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the name of the computer on which your code is running, and it is participating in a domain, then you can use [GetComputerObjectName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
#include <security.h>
#include <secext.h>

TCHAR szDN[1024];
ULONG ulSize = sizeof(szDN)/sizeof(szDN[0]);
BOOL res = GetComputerObjectName(NameFullyQualifiedDN, szDN, &ulSize);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed. BTW, for those who want to get the DN for a user, replace it with GetUserNameEx().

Comment: @user843732 Glad it helped. Its a really boring function when you're NOT domain-rooted (every option returns FALSE), but I can see it *very* helpful when you *are* on a domain.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the GetComputerNameEx function documented on 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I needed. GetComputerObjectName does the job.